# How to display month selection links inline

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="myDiv">
<a href="#" id="subtrair">-</a>

    <div id="mescorrente">March-2012</div>
<a href="#" id="somar">+</a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myDiv {
    /*display:inline;*/
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

My question is: how do I get the minus sign on the left, the name of the month at the middle and the plus sign on the right.

I've tried:

```
.myDiv {
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

And:

```
.myDiv {
    display:inline;
}
```

None worked, I know this must be easy, but I don't get it.

You may see a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nuno/krym5/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the display of all the containing element to `inline-block`:

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yb3rD/)

```
#subtrair, #mescorrente, #somar {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

If you want padding between the elements, add it to the `#mescorrente` element [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/fFAtc/):

```
#mescorrente {
    padding:0 6px;
}
```

Comment: @NunoNogueira Right - that's the parent element. It may be necessary to position *it*, but if you want the containing elements inline, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: It works well with the minus and plus signs but I'm using icons from jquery (ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w) and they're all messed up.

Comment: @NunoNogueira Given that they are `inline` elements, you could change the `vertical-align` property if they are vertically out of alignment.. Try something like `vertical-align:middle`. If you post an example, I'll take a loot at it.